# Error Message: Could not load type 'Global.Apps.Forms.NewVehicleRegistration.NewVehicleReg'

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am getting an error message, and I not quite sure where the issue would be; Any ideas?

```
    Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Global.Apps.Forms.NewVehicle.NewVehicleReg'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewVehicleReg.aspx.cs" Inherits="Global.Apps.Forms.NewVehicle.NewVehicleReg" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


Source File: /globalprocurement/apps/Forms/NewVehicle/NewVehicleReg.aspx    Line: 1 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306155). It seems that ASP.NET cannot find the compiled assembly with the code behind containing the page class definition.

Comment: This article says it applies to asp 1.0
Do you think it would still apply to framework 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the namespace is correct and matches the one in the code-behind file. Also ensure that the project builds correctly, it may be that the project fails to build, and your app is referencing an out of date version.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur if you remove the assembly in your "Web.config". Make sure you don't have a `<clear/>` like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <clear/>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```